# Predict multiple output for regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-analysis

The data consists of 24 numbers. After creating my training and test data, I want to predict these X and Y (both numbers). How should I proceed and which prediction algorithm/model should I use? I belive I can not use Linear Regression since I have multiple outputs. Another question is should I keep my data in csv or pandas dataframe? Which one is better to handle later?

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,4,5`
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4`

...

Data to be predicted:
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,X,Y`

I know there is not only one approach but it is better to learn some keywords  and I can research further.